# How can you intuit Information Implication with 4 Truth Values?

Tags: logic

<sub>Source: p 158. [*Sweet Reason: A Field Guide to Modern Logic*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444337157) (2010 2 ed) by Henle, Garfield, Tymoczko.</sub>

> [...] Call this Information Implication. 
>   Its truth table looks like this:
>
> [image]

This question focuses on the 5 rows numbered in red above. I already understand how to conclude the Truth Values for ⟹; so please do not answer with formal proofs or Truth Tables.

My problem: they still feel  counterintuitive. So can they be intuited or explained directly, without relying on the intermediate step  [(B → S) ≡ (¬B ∨ S)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/37006/8572)? For example, consider 8 and 12: how does it make intuitive sense for the Truth Value to differ from A's or B's?

Comment: Why would you expect something this artificially constructed to be intuitive?

Comment: @jobermark This is artificially constructed, but was constructed to expand on (and maintain) the normal 2-valued Material Implication. So all the possibilities with A = 0 or 1 are intuitive to me, because of the Principle of Explosion when A = 0.