# Without truth tables, how can I deduce that P → Q ≡ ¬P ∨ Q?

Tags: logic

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason  (1st edn 2008)*](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 108.

I changed the author's choice of first names, to ones that start with P and Q to fit the title.

I symbolized the disjunctions in square brackets. Please don't use truth tables.

¬P ∨ Q  never appears in these quoted sentences. So how can I conclude ¬P ∨ Q from them?

> An exclusive
>   disjunction, such as:
>
> > Either Pia helped or Quinn helped, but not both
>
> is equivalent to the proposition:
>
> > Pia  helped or the Quinn helped, and not both Pia helped and the  Quinn 
> >     helped.
>
> Hence, exclusive disjunction also has a logical meaning.
>   In an analogous way we can define a logical meaning of “if”. The sentence:
>
> > If Pia  didn’t help then  Quinn  did. [If ¬P, then Q.]
>
> means:
>
> > Pia  helped or  Quinn  did, or both. [P ∨ Q]
>
> In its logical meaning, the conditional is compatible with three possibilities: Pia  didn’t help and Quinn did [¬P ∧ Q] , Pia  helped and Quinn didn’t [P ∧ ¬Q], Pia helped and Quinn helped [P ∧ Q]. The only possibility that the conditional
>   rules out is that neither the Pia nor Quinn helped [¬P ∧ ¬Q]. The three possibilities
>   that the conditional allows are the same as those for the inclusive disjunction.

p. 478 (footnote for Ch. 21) introduces the psychology:

> 309. Ormerod and his colleagues show that participants can infer conditionals from
>        disjunctions, and disjunctions from conditionals (see Ormerod *et al.*, 1993, and
>        Richardson and Ormerod, 1997). For example, given the conditional:
>
> > If Phil’s next grant application isn’t going to be funded then he’ll be
> >     disappointed
>
> we can infer the disjunction:
>
> > Phil’s next grant application is going to be funded or he’ll be disappointed
>
> But, the results corroborate a prediction from the model theory: it is easier to
>   make the converse inference from a disjunction to a conditional. They also bear out
>   Ormerod’s claim—now embodied in the model theory—that we prefer to work with
>   as parsimonious models as possible. In unpublished studies, Sonja Geiger has found
>   that participants who carry out this paraphrasing task before they estimate the probability of a conditional tend to take more possibilities into account in their estimates

Comment: As noted by the author:  "If Pia didn't help then Quinn did" means "P ∨ Q".  In other words "¬P --> Q" means " P ∨ Q".  Thus, writing "P" for "¬P" we get  "P --> Q" means " ¬P ∨ Q"

Comment: No need to apologise.  We all have a off moments.  Lord know I do!

Comment: Already asked many times... See e.g. [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39047/how-can-you-intuit-that-p-%e2%86%92-q-%e2%89%a1-%c2%acp-%e2%88%a8-q-and-%e2%89%a2-p-%e2%88%a8-%c2%acq).

Comment: I think this is actually different enough to warrant reopening---that's why I answered it. OP is asking for a formal proof, not an intuitive justification.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll say that the paragraph implicitly uses truth tables to compare the cases where `P -> Q` and `~P v Q`, finding them to be the same.

Any statement that can be proven with a proof table (ie, any statement in sentential logic) can be proven with natural deduction instead. And natural deduction can be extended to prove statements in several other, more-powerful logics. There's a number of ways to formalize natural deduction; I'll use the system in [*forall x: Calgary Remix*](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/) because it's freely available online and has [an automatic proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) (which is what I used to write the proof below).

(I learned natural deduction using [Teller's *A Modern Formal Logic Primer*](http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/), which I think is superior, but it doesn't have as many modern comforts.)

[image]

This might all be a bit hard to understand. I'll give explanation a shot, but unfortunately I don't think there's a good, concise way to explain what's going on; you've just got to learn natural deduction or it won't make sense.

I start with the premise `P -> Q` and then assume towards contradiction that `~(Q v ~Q)`. As I'm able to derive a contradiction from that statement, it must be false; therefore I can conclude `~~(Q v ~Q)`, which is equivalent to `Q v ~Q`.

If we have `A v B`, and `A -> C` and `B -> C`, then it must be the case that `C`, because no matter which is true between `A` and `B`, `C` is also true. So the second half of the proof is showing that `Q` and `~Q`, in combination with our premise of `P -> Q`, both imply `~P v Q`. QED.